# Using Modi OCR To extract text from image

Tags: c#, ocr, modi

I Planned to use OCR in my project and searched more OCR methods and i didnt find anything correctly. And at last i heard about `MODI` and i tried that . But It throwing Following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {40942A6C-1520-4132-BDF8-BDC1F71F547B} failed due to the following error: 80040154

I'm Using `Microsoft Office 2013` and `visual studio 2012`.

The code me using is follows:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckFileType(@"E:\\");
}

public void CheckFileType(string directoryPath) 
{ 
    IEnumerator files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator(); 
    while (files.MoveNext()) 
    { 
    //get file extension 
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(files.Current));

    //get file name without extenstion 
    string fileName=Convert.ToString(files.Current).Replace(fileExtension,string.Empty);

    //Check for JPG File Format 
    if (fileExtension == ".jpg" || fileExtension == ".JPG") // or // ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString()
    { 
    try 
    { 
    //OCR Operations ... 
    MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document(); 
    md.Create(Convert.ToString(files.Current)); 
    md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true); 
    MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];
    //create text file with the same Image file name 
    FileStream createFile = new FileStream(fileName + ".txt",FileMode.CreateNew);

    //save the image text in the text file 
    StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(createFile); 
    writeFile.Write(image.Layout.Text); 
    writeFile.Close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
    MessageBox.Show("This Image hasn't a text or has a problem", 
    "OCR Notifications", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
    } 
    } 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone help me in this ? Is that problem based on Microsoft Office version or Do i Need to make any changes ? Is that any better `OCR` `dll` ? thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that Microsoft Office Document Imaging(MODI) has been discontinued with MS Office 2010. This is collaborated to OneNote in Office 2013.

Even I am still searching for the solutions or if there are any other tools to extract text from images programaticaly. If you know of any or have the solution, please share it.